# Having trouble dynamically plotting bar graph [AChartEngine]

Tags: android, achartengine

I've been trying to dynamically plot bar graphs on Android but to no avail.

I seem to be missing something in my codes but I cannot figure out what is it. I made a new project which helps illustrate my problem clearly. This code should allow the bar graph to change when the button is pressed, but when its pressed it looks like it only has been cleared, but not repainted. This is my MainActivity.java code:

```
    package com.example.dynamicbargraph;

    import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.app.Activity;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private BarGraph bar = new BarGraph();
        private GraphicalView barView;


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //bar graph view initialize
            barView = bar.getBarView(this);
            LinearLayout barLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.barchart);
            barLayout.addView(barView);


        }

        public void buttonHandler(View view)
        {
            LinearLayout barLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.barchart);
            barLayout.removeView(barView);
            bar.staticPlot();
            barView.repaint();
        }

    }
```

This is the BarGraph.java code:

```
    package com.example.dynamicbargraph;

    import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
    import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
    import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
    import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
    import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;


    public class BarGraph {

        private GraphicalView view;

        private CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Accelerometer");
        private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        private XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); //used for customizing
        private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public BarGraph()
        {


            int[] y ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                series.add("Bar" + (i+1), y[i]);
            }


            dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());


            //below are just customization codes
            renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);
            renderer.setColor(Color.GRAY);


            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
            mRenderer.setChartTitle("Arm Steadiness From Device");
            mRenderer.setXTitle("Frequency (Hz)");
            mRenderer.setYTitle("Magnitude");

            float textSize = 30, textSmaller = 20, angle = 270;
            mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(textSize);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsAngle(angle);
            mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(textSize);
            mRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(textSize);
            mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(textSmaller);
            mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(textSize);
            mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.rgb(112, 128, 144));

            //adjusting margin width of y-axis (so y axis labels can be seen)
            int[] i = mRenderer.getMargins();
            i[0] += 50;//top
            i[1] += 50;//left (increment here)
            //i[2] = 0;//bottom
            //i[3] = 0;//right   
            mRenderer.setMargins(i);
        }

        public GraphicalView getBarView(Context context)
        {
            view = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
            return view;
        }

        public void staticPlot()
        {
            int[] y ={10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                series.add("Bar" + (i+1), y[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, the activity_main.xml code that calls the buttonHandler when clicked:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/barchart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="buttonHandler"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I know I am missing something in the buttonHandler, but I don't know what is it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void buttonHandler(View view)
{
    LinearLayout barLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.barchart);
    barLayout.removeView(barView);
    bar.staticPlot();

    barView = bar.getBarView(this); //Grab the newest graph

    barLayout.addView(barView);
    barView.repaint();
}

public void staticPlot() {

    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); //Clear the previous dataset (maybe there is a remove instead?)

    int[] y = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    series.clear(); //Clear your previous values

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        series.add("Bar" + (i + 1), y[i]);
    }

    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries()); //Readd to dataset
}
```

Works on my machine, hope this helps, explanation is in comments

Edit: more comments / typos

Comment: it works, thanks for your help! and also your very useful videos

Answer (score 0):

In your onClickListener, it looks like you're removing the View from it's parent LinearLayout and then trying to repaint without re-adding it. I'm not sure what the point of removing it is, so maybe try this:

```
public void buttonHandler(View view) {
        if(bar != null) {
            //LinearLayout barLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.barchart);
            //barLayout.removeView(barView);
            bar.staticPlot();
            bar.repaint();
        }
    }
```

Forget removing it from the Layout and just repaint it. Keep in mind, your staticPlot method will always draw the same thing (but you probably knew that when you called it "staticPlot"), so don't expect varying results except additional series of the same data points.

```
public void staticPlot() {
        int[] y ={ 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) series.add("Bar" + (i+1), y[i]);
        // dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); <--- You may want to create a new dataset if you're not going to create a new series
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    }
```

Hope that points you in the right direction~

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've tried that before but nothing happens, so i tried to removeView then repaint again.

Comment: In your staticPlot method, there's a couple things that also seem off. The first is that you're editing the initial series, but never actually updating the dataset by calling dataset.addSeries(series.toXySeries); which explains why it's not updating because the actual dataset has never changed. Your dataset is built off a new object created by toXySeries() and explains why nothing is changing. Updating answer in a second...

Comment: Yes I realised that before, but when i included dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries); in the staticPlot method, the app crashes. If it didnt I think it would work.

Comment: Try creating a secondary series inside the staticPlot before adding data to it: series = new CategorySeries("Series2");

Comment: the app crashes unless i create a new XYMultipleSeriesDataset in staticPlot, but the graph still does not change. Thanks for your help nonetheless

Comment: You should post stack traces from the LogCat; they literally tell you what the error is and exactly what line of code is causing it to occur, which will helps us isolate the issue. And my guess the reason it's failing is because it's already attached to a series renderer.